# Is it possible to call a variable from a method without passing as a return variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a library for some bird population parameters in different ecosystems. In order to not repeat code I want to take some variables defined in a previous method and use these in other method without passing this variable as return. For example

```
class asd:
    
    def __init__(self): 
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def fun1(self):
        self.a2 = self.a * 2

    def fun2(self):
        self.a4 = self.a2*2 #this is what i want to do.
```

Comment: ... use an instance variable?

Comment: Even with an instance variable, _someone_ should first call `fun1` in order for `self_a2` to be calculated.

Comment: You could write fun2 to check if self.a2 exists, and if it doesn't, call fun1, but I think this is a lot of work to avoid using return values.

Comment: @ExaltedToast but why? You don't have to check. An indeed, throwing an error in that case would be the best design generally speaking

Comment: Why, oh why, are you naming your local variables like, `self_*`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Checking for existence of an instance attribute is common practice, but it is usually used for caching expensive functions. In this example it makes little sense.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that would violate at least one PEP8 item, and will piss off some linters (which is good). Defining instance attributes in arbitrary methods is asking for trouble. By the very least OP should set `self.a4 = None` (or any other sentinel value) in `__init__`.

Comment: @Selcuk sure, but that is a specific use-case. Here there seems to be some dependence on the order that the methods are called. In which case, letting the attribute error be (or maybe catching it and raising one with a better description) makes the most sense

Answer (score 1):

As @ffm_nosoup has stated, this is not possible as requested because of function scopes.

The general way to accomplish this sort of thing is to store any values you want in the class itself, and reference those values. Assuming the result of `fun1` is expensive to compute and you don't want to recompute it when possible, your specific example might be rewritten as:

```py
class Asd:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.a2 = None

    def fun1(self):
        self.a2 = self.a * 2

    def fun2(self):
        if self.a2 is None:
            raise ValueError("Attempted to use result from fun1() without first calling fun1()")
        self.a4 = self.a2 * 2
```

Alternatively, you might auto-call `fun1`, but this can be a riskier design choice in some instances.

```py
def fun2(self):
    if self.a2 is None:
        self.fun1()
    self.a4 = self.a2 * 2
```

A third option is to just use a [cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), which will only compute the function once and reuse that result in the future. (As Mark Ransom points out in the comments, this will lead to issues if you ever need to recompute the result of fun1.)

```py
from functools import lru_cache

class Asd:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @lru_cache
    def fun1(self):
        return self.a * 2

    def fun2(self):
        self.a4 = self.fun1() * 2
```

Comment: I don't know if ValueError is the appropriate error in python, in Java I would raise an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Ohh, thanks! i didn't understand when they were talking about checking. I'll try this I'll see what happen. As you said, the parameters i need are very expensive, so i dont want to calculate these everytime i call the function.

Comment: `ValueError` is perfectly fine. After all, a variable indeed has an invalid value

Comment: Doesn't `lru_cache` require passing the value as a parameter?

Comment: @MarkRansom [A quick test](https://hastebin.com/edosuyicuh.rb) verifies that lru_cache can function on methods without parameters, and will also correctly change values between instances.

Comment: @ExaltedToast your example assumes `self.x` never changes.  Try changing it and see what happens.

Comment: Ah, you meant like that. The other solutions will suffer from the same issue unless fun1 is recalculated, but this is a valid drawback of the cache method if it's necessary and nontrivial to transform the class variables to function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A good option to achieve this without messing with variable scopes, is to initialise `self.a2` with a sentinel value, typically `None`.

Then you can check `self.a2` inside your `fun2()` and react accordingly, i.e. call `fun1()` before the expression:

```
class asd:
        
    def __init__(self): 
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.a2 = None

    def fun1(self):
        self.a2 = self.a * 2

    def fun2(self):
        if self.a2 is None:
            self.fun1()
        self.a4 = self.a2*2
```

Actually you can also get rid of the sentinel var, and use `hasattr()` as a check:

```
class asd:
    
    def __init__(self): 
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def fun1(self):
        self.a2 = self.a * 2

    def fun2(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "a2")
            self.fun1()
        self.a4 = self.a2*2
```

This may be useful if your `self.a2` could be assigned any value, `None` included, thus defeating the sentinel purpose. It's not the case though, since you're using it in a mathematical expression.

Comment: Wow! I dindn't think about the first option. Is great! Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

No this isn't possible variables always only exist in their scope. you need to work with global variables to achieve what you want or you have to overwrite your instance variables. It depends on the problem you'd like to solve and the design of your code.

Comment: Ok, i just wanted to check if it was possible. I'm taking this little project to learn and so I'm trying to look for all the possibilities.

Comment: OP, by definition, does *not* **need** to work with global variables (which is usually frowned upon since it creates spaghetti code which is a nightmare to maintain). Returning values or using an instance attributes is the way to go

Comment: To be clear, it **is** possible, but you need to change your approach as discussed in the comments under your question. This answer is, well, not an answer as it doesn't tell how to properly implement it. A comment would be more suitable.

Comment: ok i agree that it doesn't need to global variables, @DeepSpace and I see why global variables are frowned when programming big projects in an object oriented manner  but when talking about small f.e. automation scripts, in my opionen, global variables can be useful?

Comment: Since old habits die hard, I'd avoid them in small projects as well. Not using global variables is pretty easy. It is easier to getting used to not using them at all than trying to not use them in individual, "larger" projects